# What is the easiest way to sort an ArrayList of strings

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

What is the easiest way to sort this ArrayList without any complicated methods involved:

```
 ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
 myList.add("1");
 myList.add("2");
 myList.add("3");
 myList.add("4");
```

I would like an alternative to the `Comparator` way of doing it as that makes things complicated.

Want to sort the list in the ascending order of the strings as shown below:

Ignore the fact that I have letters contained in the string, just assume I only have numbers:
I want myList to print out the following if it is sorted in ascending order:

So if I have the following elements in my list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 100, 40, 50] (as I put them in)

I get the output as [1, 100, 12, 2, 3, 4, 40, 50] after I use `Collections.sort(myList)`

This is not what I want, I want the output to be in number order such as [1,2,3,4,12,40,50,100] ranging from smallest to largest

Comment: It depends on how you want to sort your list. `Collections.sort(myList)` will sort your list according to the natural ordering of its elements. Otherwise you will have to provide a custom comparator.

Comment: Thanks forgot to add that, just made the edit

Comment: Ascending according to what order? Words length maybe?

Comment: Ascending order as in if I have 4 numbers (1,2,3,4) I want to sort the list so it displays the order as such: 1,2,3,4

Comment: @RymanHolmes May I suggest you to use a `List<Integer>` ? Any reasons that you use a `List<String>` ?

Comment: @ZouZou No because each element may contain letters and numbers

Comment: @RymanHolmes `each element may contain letters and numbers` in that case how should elements be ordered? How would you like to order `a, 1, 21, 12, a2, 2b` elements?

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: @Pshemo order the elements from lowest to highest so numbers first then letters

Comment: @RymanHolmes Don't post this information as comment but rather include it in your question. Also to improve your question add example with few kinds of elements you can have in your lists like only letters, only numbers, mixed. Also use different length of elements. Post them in unsorted and sorted order.

Comment: Have updated the question with an example

Comment: @RymanHolmes OK, now your question makes more sense. I am voting to reopen it. Anyway why don't you want to use custom Comparator? In case you only have numbers it would be easy to convert your data to lets say integers and as result of Comparator return result of `Integer.compare(x,y);` where `x` and `y` would be values converted from String to integers.

Comment: not sure how the custom Comparator actually orders the elements in the list, I need to see an example and not sure what the compare method does either

Comment: @RymanHolmes Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). It explains what Comparators are, how to write and use them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Collections.sort(List<T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) for that:

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

---

An excerpt from the javadoc:

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the
>   natural ordering of its elements. **All elements in the list must
>   implement the Comparable interface.** Furthermore, all elements in the
>   list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not
>   throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).